# Order By Used with Case Statement

Tags: sql-server-2005

i use Order By Used with Case Statement and may be this is the reason for which i am getting error `Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.`

here is my complete sql where i use Row_Number function for pagination with sorting. please guide me where i made the mistake.

```
DECLARE @StartIndex INT
DECLARE @EndIndex   INT

DECLARE @SortColumn VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SortDirection VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @StartIndex = 1
SET @EndIndex = 20
SET @SortColumn = 'OrderID'
SET @SortColumn = 'A'

SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (
    ORDER BY
        CASE (@SortColumn + ':' + @SortDirection)
            WHEN 'OrderID:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.OrderID ASC)
            WHEN 'OrderID:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.OrderID DESC)
            WHEN 'CustomerID:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.CustomerID ASC)
            WHEN 'CustomerID:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.CustomerID DESC)
            WHEN 'EmployeeID:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.EmployeeID ASC)
            WHEN 'EmployeeID:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.EmployeeID DESC)
            WHEN 'OrderDate:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.OrderDate ASC)
            WHEN 'OrderDate:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.OrderDate DESC)
            WHEN 'RequiredDate:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.RequiredDate ASC)
            WHEN 'RequiredDate:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.RequiredDate DESC)
            WHEN 'ShippedDate:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.OrderID ASC)
            WHEN 'ShippedDate:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.OrderID DESC)
            WHEN 'ShipVia:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipVia ASC)
            WHEN 'ShipVia:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipVia DESC)
            WHEN 'Freight:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.Freight ASC)
            WHEN 'Freight:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.Freight DESC)
            WHEN 'ShipName:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipName ASC)
            WHEN 'ShipName:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipName DESC)
            WHEN 'ShipAddress:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipAddress ASC)
            WHEN 'ShipAddress:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipAddress DESC)
            WHEN 'ShipCity:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipCity ASC)
            WHEN 'ShipCity:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipCity DESC)
            WHEN 'ShipRegion:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipRegion ASC)
            WHEN 'ShipRegion:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipRegion DESC)
            WHEN 'ShipPostalCode:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipPostalCode ASC)
            WHEN 'ShipPostalCode:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipPostalCode DESC)
            WHEN 'ShipCountry:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipCountry ASC)
            WHEN 'ShipCountry:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipCountry DESC)

        END 
  ) BETWEEN (@StartIndex - 1) * @EndIndex + 1 AND @StartIndex * @EndIndex 
  /* AND more conditions ... */
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 'A' THEN
    CASE @SortColumn 
        WHEN 'OrderID'    THEN OrderID
        WHEN 'CustomerID' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'EmployeeID' THEN CustomerID      
        WHEN 'OrderDate' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'RequiredDate' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'ShippedDate' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'ShipVia' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'Freight' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'ShipName' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'ShipAddress' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'ShipCity' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'ShipRegion' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'ShipPostalCode' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'ShipCountry' THEN CustomerID
    END
  END,
  CASE WHEN @SortDirection = 'D' THEN
    CASE @SortColumn 
        WHEN 'OrderID'    THEN OrderID
        WHEN 'CustomerID' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'EmployeeID' THEN CustomerID      
        WHEN 'OrderDate' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'RequiredDate' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'ShippedDate' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'ShipVia' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'Freight' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'ShipName' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'ShipAddress' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'ShipCity' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'ShipRegion' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'ShipPostalCode' THEN CustomerID
        WHEN 'ShipCountry' THEN CustomerID
    END 
  END DESC
```

### EDIT 1

i change my code as per your one but still getting same error. here is new code

```
DECLARE @StartIndex INT
DECLARE @EndIndex   INT

DECLARE @SortColumn VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SortDirection VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @StartIndex = 1
SET @EndIndex = 20
SET @SortColumn = 'CustomerID'
SET @SortDirection = 'D'

;WITH cte as(SELECT *, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                    (ORDER BY 
                        CASE (@SortColumn + ':' + @SortDirection)
                            WHEN 'OrderID:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.OrderID ASC)
                            WHEN 'OrderID:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.OrderID DESC)
                            WHEN 'CustomerID:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.CustomerID ASC)
                            WHEN 'CustomerID:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.CustomerID DESC)
                            WHEN 'EmployeeID:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.EmployeeID ASC)
                            WHEN 'EmployeeID:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.EmployeeID DESC)
                            WHEN 'OrderDate:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.OrderDate ASC)
                            WHEN 'OrderDate:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.OrderDate DESC)
                            WHEN 'RequiredDate:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.RequiredDate ASC)
                            WHEN 'RequiredDate:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.RequiredDate DESC)
                            WHEN 'ShippedDate:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.OrderID ASC)
                            WHEN 'ShippedDate:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.OrderID DESC)
                            WHEN 'ShipVia:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipVia ASC)
                            WHEN 'ShipVia:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipVia DESC)
                            WHEN 'Freight:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.Freight ASC)
                            WHEN 'Freight:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.Freight DESC)
                            WHEN 'ShipName:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipName ASC)
                            WHEN 'ShipName:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipName DESC)
                            WHEN 'ShipAddress:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipAddress ASC)
                            WHEN 'ShipAddress:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipAddress DESC)
                            WHEN 'ShipCity:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipCity ASC)
                            WHEN 'ShipCity:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipCity DESC)
                            WHEN 'ShipRegion:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipRegion ASC)
                            WHEN 'ShipRegion:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipRegion DESC)
                            WHEN 'ShipPostalCode:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipPostalCode ASC)
                            WHEN 'ShipPostalCode:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipPostalCode DESC)
                            WHEN 'ShipCountry:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipCountry ASC)
                            WHEN 'ShipCountry:D' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Orders.ShipCountry DESC)
                        END 
                     ) rn
             FROM Orders)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE rn BETWEEN (@StartIndex - 1) * @EndIndex + 1 AND @StartIndex * @EndIndex
```

Comment: You made the mistake when you used window function in `where` clause...

Comment: would u tell me what to rectify.

Comment: Construct the dynamic query. `declare @sql nvarchar(max) = "your query"` and execute it `exec(@sql)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already figured it out you can not use window function in `where` clause. Just do it in cte or subquery and then filter it outside:

```
;WITH cte as(SELECT *, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                    (ORDER BY CASE WHEN (@SortColumn + ':' + @SortDirection) = 'OrderID:A' 
                                   THEN Orders.OrderID ASC END,
                              CASE WHEN (@SortColumn + ':' + @SortDirection) = 'OrderID:D' 
                                   THEN Orders.OrderID DESC END,
                              ...) rn
             FROM Orders)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE rn BETWEEN (@StartIndex - 1) * @EndIndex + 1 AND @StartIndex * @EndIndex 
  /* AND more conditions ... */
ORDER BY
...
--same case expressions here
```

As you have noticed instead of one big case expression you will have to have many because you can not use different types in one case expressions as you will get conversion errors.

But from my experience it is better to have dynamic sql with parametrised parameters because sql engine will save the execution plans for each case and will be much more quick then having such a big complicated query.

Dynamic version:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = ';WITH cte as(SELECT *, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                    (ORDER BY ' + CASE (@SortColumn + ':' + @SortDirection) 
                                    WHEN 'OrderID:A' THEN 'Orders.OrderID ASC'
                                    WHEN 'OrderID:D' THEN 'Orders.OrderID DESC'
                                    ...
                                    WHEN 'ShipCountry:D' THEN 'Orders.ShipCountry DESC' END + 
                              ') rn
             FROM Orders)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE rn BETWEEN ' + CAST((@StartIndex - 1) * @EndIndex + 1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + ' AND ' + 
                     CAST(@StartIndex * @EndIndex AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: see my edit 1 portion. i still getting error even after follow your guide line like CTE. any idea ?

Comment: `WHEN 'OrderID:A' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ` remove row_numbers here. See my answer carefully.

Comment: can u point me to any dynamic sql script where i will pass startindex, endindex, sortcol and order and query return data accordingly. thanks

Comment: thanks for your 2nd code but when i use dynamic sql then why should i use case statement.....then it is not required.